# I try to install tensorflowjs in Linux and after some time I get the following error

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow.js

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error                

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.                                           │ exit code: 1                                       ╰─> [14 lines of output]

      running dist_info                                    creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info                                           writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                   writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

      writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/requires.txt

      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/top_level.txt

      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any

      reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      adding license file 'LICENSE'

      adding license file 'AUTHORS'

      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore-0.1.27.dist-info'

      error: [('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/PKG-INFO', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/PKG-INFO', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/PKG-INFO'"), ('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/dependency_links.txt', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/dependency_links.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/dependency_links.txt'"), ('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/requires.txt', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/requires.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/requires.txt'"), ('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/top_level.txt', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/top_level.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/top_level.txt'"), ('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/SOURCES.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__/SOURCES.txt'"), ('/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-njx28l3p/tensorstore.egg-info.__bkp__'")]

      [end of output]                                                                                       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                    error: metadata-generation-failed                    

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.

╰─> See above for output.                                                                                 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.                                         hint: See above for details.
```

I installed the pyproject.toml and thought it would work and it didn't work.

Comment: can you show the command you entered?

Comment: I entered the command "pip install tensorflowjs".

Comment: please try `sudo pip install tensorflowjs`

Comment: I'm going to try...

Comment: Yes, that did work and.... What do I do with the files I tried to install earlier, I think they stayed in the device memory, how can I delete them? Well, and thanks for your help!

Comment: just remove the ones you have downloaded.